# Fuzzy Like This on Attachment Returns Nothing on Partial Word

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

I have my mapping like this:

```
    {
      "doc": {
        "mappings": {
          "mydocument": {
            "properties": {
              "file": {
                "type": "attachment",
                "path": "full",
                "fields": {
                  "file": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
                  },
                  "author": {
...
```

When I search for a complete word I get the result:

```
  "query": {
        "fuzzy_like_this" : {
          "fields" : ["file"],
          "like_text" : "This_is_something_I_want_to_search_for",
          "max_query_terms" : 12
        }
    },
  "highlight" : {
    "number_of_fragments" : 3,
    "fragment_size" : 650,
    "fields" : {
      "file" : {  }
    }
  }
```

But if I change the search term to `"This_is_something_I_want"` I get nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement a partial match, we must first understand what `fuzzy like this` does and then decide what you want partial matching to return. `fuzzy like this` will perform 2 key functions.

1. The `like_text` will be analyzed using the default analyzer. All the resulting tokens will then be used to find documents based on term frequency, or `tf-idf`

This typically means that the input term will be be split on space and lowercased. `This_is_something_I_want` will therefore be tokenized to `this_is_something_i_want`. Unless you have files with this exact term, no documents will match.

2. Secondly, all terms will be `fuzzified`. Fuzzy searches score terms based on how many character changes needs to made to a word to match another word. For instance to get from `bat` to `hat` we will need to make 1 character change.

For our case to get from `this_is_something_i_want` to `this_is_something_i_want_to_search_for`, we will need to make 14 character changes (adding `_to_search_for`.) Standard fuzzy search only allows for 3 character changes when working with terms longer that 5 or 6 characters. Increasing the fuzzy limit to 14 will however produce severely skewed results

So neither of these functions will help produce the results you seek.

Here is what I can suggest:

1. You can implement an analyzer that splits on underscore similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244519/elasticsearch-custom-analyzer-for-hyphens-underscores-and-numbers). Tokens produced will then be `['this', 'is', 'something', 'i', 'want']` which can correctly be matched to to the sample case
2. Alternatively, if all you want is a document that starts with the specified text, you can use a `phrase prefix` query instead of `fuzzy like this`. Documentations [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This is great information and learning for me.