# Search for two fields but only score once in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, relevance

Let's say I have these documents in Elasticsearch:

```
{
    "display_name": "Jose Cummings",
    "username": "josecummings"
},
{
    "display_name": "Jose Ramirez",
    "username": "elite_gamer"
},
{
    "display_name": "Lance Abrams",
    "username": "abrams1"
},
{
    "display_name": "Steve Smith",
    "username": "josesmose"
}
```

I want to run a "as you type" search for `Jose` that searches against both the `display_name` and the `username` fields, which I can do with this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": [
                        "display_name",
                        "username"
                    ],
                    "query": "Jose",
                    "type": "bool_prefix",
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                    "boost": 50
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that when I search for `Jose`, Jose Cummings gets 100 points while Jose Ramirez and Steve Smith only get 50 points, because it seems to sum the scores for the two fields. This essentially rewards a user for having the same `display_name` as `username`, which we do not want to happen.

Is there a way to only take the max score from the two fields? I've tried dozens of different combinations now using `function_score`, `boost_mode`/`score_mode`, `constant_score`, trying to do a `should` match with multiple `match_bool_prefix` queries, etc. Nothing I've tried seems to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "display_name^50",
              "username^50"
            ],
            "query": "Jose",
            "type": "bool_prefix",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "tie_breaker": 0.3
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the effects of the [`tie_breaker`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#tie-breaker) being set to 0.0 as opposed to 0<x<1 and x=1.

---

Also note that your [`bool_prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-bool-prefix)

> scoring behaves like `most_fields`, but using a `match_bool_prefix` query instead of a `match` query.

Perhaps you indeed want the fields to be prefixed w/ `jose`. But if the username is, say, `cool_jose`, it's going to get left out (unless you for example apply an other-than-standard [analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245612/8160318))...

Comment: I think `tie_breaker` set to 0 works the way I was intending it to. At least in initial tests. I'll implement later and assuming it works, mark it as correct in a day or two. Thank you. For your second note, this is for a search-as-you-type deal. I do indeed want to use a prefix. I have a second endpoint for a more generic match and the frontend guys don't like the way it behaves for the use cases.

Comment: I hear ya. OK cool, let me know how the testing went.

Comment: After implementing it in the application, it seems to do exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Glad to have helped!